# scenarios for bucket sort and counting sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

This has been confusing me for a while.I would like to know scenarios where in bucket sort should be used
over counting sort (or vice-verse).

Comment: What is counting sort?

Answer (score 2):

These two pages provide some informations on both sort.

- [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)
- [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

**About the counting sort:**

> Because counting sort uses key values as indexes into an array, it is
>   not a comparison sort, and the Ω(n log n) lower bound for comparison
>   sorting does not apply to it.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) Bucket sort may be used for many of
>   the same tasks as counting sort, with a similar time analysis;
>   however, compared to counting sort, bucket sort requires linked lists,
>   dynamic arrays or a large amount of preallocated memory to hold the
>   sets of items within each bucket, whereas counting sort instead stores
>   a single number (the count of items) per bucket.[4]

**About the bucket sort:**

> Bucket sort can be seen as a generalization of counting sort; in fact,
>   if each bucket has size 1 then bucket sort degenerates to counting
>   sort. The variable bucket size of bucket sort allows it to use O(n)
>   memory instead of O(M) memory, where M is the number of distinct
>   values; in exchange, it gives up counting sort's O(n + M) worst-case
>   behavior.